# Determining the orbit of a vector field in curved space

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

Suppose one is working in Kruskal space-time with metric in the usual Kruskal $(U,V)$ coordinates:

$$ds^2 = -\dfrac{32M^3e^{r/2M}}{r}dUdV+r^2d\Omega_2^2$$

Where $r$ now defined implicitly in terms of $U,V$ was originally the radial coordinate of Schwarzschild, and $d\Omega_2$ is the usual round metric on $S_2$.

I want to systematically determine the orbits of $k=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} = \dfrac{1}{4M}\left(V\dfrac{\partial}{\partial V} - U\dfrac{\partial}{\partial U}\right)$. How does one go about determining these orbits?

In the notes I'm following, the author presents the following diagram of the orbits without any calculation. To me, this implies that it's supposedly obvious, but I can't see how to determine this.

If it helps, I'm familiar with the mathematical notions of integral curves of a vector field i.e. that the orbits of a vector field are curves for which the vector field is everywhere tangent, but I'm not sure how to apply it in practice here.

Any pedagogical assistance is very welcome!

[image: Orbits of k]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the orbits of $k$ just means finding a curve $(U(\lambda), V(\lambda))$ such that $dU/d\lambda = k^U$ and $dV/d\lambda = k^V$. Written out, these equations are

$$\frac{dV}{d\lambda} = \frac{V}{4M}$$

$$\frac{dU}{d\lambda} = -\frac{U}{4M}$$

The solution is $V(\lambda) = V_0 \exp(\lambda/4M)$, $U(\lambda) = U_0 \exp(-\lambda/4M)$, where $U_0$ and $V_0$ are constants that depend on the initial conditions. Now we could pick values for these constants and plot the parametric curves, but it's much easier to just note that on each curve we have $UV = \text{const}$, so they are the hyperbolae you see in the picture.